# Virtual keyboard is hiding the settings panel pages in windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

### Heading ##I have  a login page in my one of the pages in settings flyout.I have used this code(windows 8.1)

```
       int flyoutOffset = 0;
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Showing += (s, args) = > {
    args.EnsuredFocusedElementInView = true;
    settingsPopup.VerticalOffset = 0;
    flyoutOffset = (int) args.OccludedRect.Height;
    settingsPopup.VerticalOffset -= flyoutOffset;

};
```

If  I use this the top top text box is scrolled up and not visible.,I need to make all the controls in the flyout to be visible. Could you please help how to fix this?Thanks in Advance

Comment: Mention which platform are you are using in your question.

Comment: Does it happen even if you don't handle the `InputPane.Showing` event? If you set `EnsuredFocusElementInView` - you basically disable the platform built-in logic that moves your content around to keep the focused element visible when the input pane shows up.

Comment: If i didnt handle the InputPane.Showing event .The bottom text box is hidden